# What does しきみたい in おばけやしきみたい mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, conjugations

I'm watching to Totoro and there is a line **おばけやしきみたい**. The translation says, "It's like a haunted house." I understand that おばけ や could be roughly "relating to monsters" and the dictionary thinks that しきみたい might be a conjugation of shiku (to spread out, lay). I can't find a conjugation that would produce しきみたい.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (おばけやしき)(みたい)

You're splitting it in the wrong place. おばけやしき means "haunted house". みたい is a suffix that means "-like".

You can break down おばけやしき further into おばけ = ghost and やしき = residence.

Comment: お[化]{ば}け[屋敷]{や・しき}